# Using source to include part of a file in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I've a bash script that need to use some variables included in a separate file.

Normally, for including the entire file I would use source otherfile.sh in the main script.
In this case I need to use just a portion of this file. I can't use (include) the rest of the variables included in the rest of the file.

To filter the content of the config file (let's say just as example from the tag "# start" to "# end") I use awk, but I can't redirect the output to the soruce command.

Below my code:

```
awk ' /'"# start"'/ {flag=1;next} /'"# end"'/{flag=0} flag { print }' config.sh
```

Do you know any way to redirect the output of this command into source? Is there any other way to include the output in my bash script at run-time?

By the way, I wouldn't like to create temporaty files (it seems me too dirty...)..and I've tried something found on this site, but for some reasons it doesn't work. Below there's the solution I've found.

```
awk ' /'"# start"'/ {flag=1;next} /'"# end"'/{flag=0} flag { print }' config.sh | source /dev/stdin
```

Thank you,

Luca

Answer (score 5):

`source` can read from a process substitution in `bash`:

```
source <( awk ' ... ' config.sh )
```

`sed` allows a simpler way to get the subset of lines:

```
sed -n '/#start/,/#end/p' config.sh
```

UPDATE: It appears that this may only work in `bash` 4 or later.

Comment: Hi Chepner, I tried to execute the code above but using 'source <(sed -n '/#start/,/#end/p' config.sh)' returns line 7: source/dev/fd/63: No such file or directory. Using 'source<$(sed -n '/#start/,/#end/p' config.sh)' says line 7: $(sed -n '/#start/,/#end/p' config.sh): ambiguous redirect. I report the correct answer given by a friend today below. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Strange. I tried `source <(echo foo=bar)`, which should set the value of `foo` to "bar" in the current shell. It works as expected in `bash` 4.1 and above. It does fail in `bash` 3.2, although I don't see any error message as you report with the first attempt. The second attempt should fail, since you are trying to use the output of `sed` as a file name, which is syntactically incorrect, I think.

Answer (score 2):

A correct way of doing it provided by a friend today. Here's the code:

```
source /dev/stdin <<EOF
$(awk ' /'"# 10.216.33.133 - start"'/ {flag=1;next} /'"# 10.216.33.133 - end"'/{flag=0} flag { print }' testbed.sh)
EOF
```

Working perfectly...thanks Andrea! :) (and of course everyone tried to answer)