# How to prevent sourcing a part of a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I have a shell script with a syntax compatible to both `bash` and `zsh`, except for a section that has zsh specific syntax. that throws syntax errors if sourced from a bash
is there an easy way to escape such section when using bash.

---

The script is a bash function that sources all the files in a directory. it works fine form zsh (and it is irrelevant to the question)

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shell=$(ps -p $$ -oargs=)

if [ $shell = "bash" ]; then
    for f in ~/.functions.d/*.sh; do source $f; done
elif [ $shell = "zsh" ]; then
    for f (~/.functions.d/**/*.sh) source $f
fi
```

the error is produced by the 7th line, when sourcing it in `bash`

---

relevant links

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/242854/source-only-part-of-a-script-from-another-script
- [Using source to include part of a file in a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22183903/using-source-to-include-part-of-a-file-in-a-bash-script)

Comment: `bash` has to parse the entire script whether or not a particular block will be *executed*, so if it's really not valid `bash` syntax, you'll have to split your file into separate `bash` and `zsh` versions and have the caller choose which file to source.

Comment: thanks, is it possible to control the caller behavior from within the script ?

Comment: The 7th line is `elif [ $shell = "zsh" ]; then` I don't see why that should cause an error in `bash`. The actual problem is the `for` syntax on line 8.

Comment: OP is probably not counting the shebang. The body of the `elif` clause is invalid `bash` syntax, but must be parsed in order to locate the `fi` that finishes the entire `if` statement.

Comment: is you start counting from 0,  it's the next line. and the error is `syntax error near unexpected token (`. But as I said, my question is not about "That " script

Comment: "revilement", "irreverent"!!

Comment: in fact, I mean "irrelevant"/"relevant" respectively, nice spot though :) @WilliamPursell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the entire `if/elif/else` statement is parsed as a unit, so it can't contain invalid syntax.

What you could do is exit the sourced script before executing the zsh-specific code:

```
shell=$(ps -p $$ -oargs=)

if [ $shell = "bash" ]; then
    for f in ~/.functions.d/*.sh; do source $f; done
    return
fi

if [ $shell = "zsh" ]; then
    for f (~/.functions.d/**/*.sh) source $f
fi
```

However, a more general solution is to extract the bash-specific and zsh-specific code into separate scripts.

```
shell=$(ps -p $$ -oargs=)

if [ $shell = "bash" ]; then
    source load_functions.bash
fi

if [ $shell = "zsh" ]; then
    source load_functions.zsh
fi
```

`load_functions.bash` would contain the first `for` loop, while `load_functions.zsh` would have the second one.

Comment: Deleting the entire body of the `elif` clause will be a syntax error as well. You have to replace it with `:`.

Comment: This removes the `elif` line and its body.

Comment: Thank you, that should work, but is it possible do the check, and the replacement from the script. so that I'll always have to just run `source scrip.sh, and it check the current env, and escape the given block ?

Comment: No, it isn't. As mentioned in a comment, the shell parses the entire script first.

Comment: So you can't have invalid syntax, even if it's not executed because of `if`.

Comment: Not quite the entire script; commands are parsed on demand. But since the entire `if` statement is *one* command, the whole thing must parse correctly. You could have syntax errors *after* the `if` statement, and they'll only be parsed if execution continues after the `if` statement executes.

Comment: Ah, that suggests a solution: don't use `elif`, use `return` to exit from the sourced script.

Comment: @4015.alt I've revised the answer.

Comment: thank you & chepner; the last answer seems to resolve script issues  (which was the use of `elif` and zsh for-loop syntax. but I think that loading shell specif section from separate files as you have suggested in this [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/70382415/1) might be a more generalizable solution of the question. (w/o using `elif`). can you edit it back to the answer, in addition of the current method (or l can do it if you don't mind)

Comment: I've added that back in.

Comment: To avoid duplication of function definitions that are common to both shells, you might want to `source load_functions.sh` before the conditional.

Comment: in the case of this  particular example load_functions.bash / load_functions.zsh will just contains the bodies of the for-loops. and both will load all the script files from functions.d

Comment: @4015.alt But the zsh version also loads from subdirectories, isn't that what `**` is for?

Comment: yes, the ** to browse sub dirs, in the script above,  if a function is in a  sub directory, it will be ignored by bash (it may be an organizational choice but in my case, it was just a laziness one ( `**` in  my local bash env, isnt the same as `**` in zsh )). therefor I said that the script is just an example for a concept. and is irrelevant, to the main question.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a

```
if [[ -n ${BASH_VERSION:-} ]]
then
   : we are in bash
else
   : we are not
fi
```

The variable `BASH_VERSION` is guaranteed to be set by bash, and unless you are explicitly (malevolently) tamper with this variable, you should be fine.

Comment: this method, or checking $SHELL variable, as well as  the one in my question, will all end up sourcing the "we are not" part when you source the file in a bash environment. because as explained by chepner and Barmar, if/else|elif/fi is parsed as a unit. So the "we are not" section still have to contain a syntax compatible with bash (that was the source of my issue)

Comment: @4015.alt : `SHELL` is not necessarily set correctly. For instance, on my platform, when I invoke a `bash` subshell form my `zsh` login shell, `SHELL` still is set to `/bin/zsh`. However, `BASH_VERSION` is set, because bash itself is taking care about this variable.

Comment: @4015.alt : Aside from this, it is almost trivial to write the "outer" code (your if/else/elif/fi) in your question in a way that it works with bash and zsh alike. It was just because you decided on unnecessarily using a special zsh construct in the "zsh" branch, which has set up the bash parser and caused trouble.